# On a problem of sphere-packing for Reed-Solomon codes

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, coding-theory

Suppose we have an $[n, k+1, n-k]$ Reed Solomon code $\mathcal C$ over $\mathbb F_q$, where $n-k=d$ is the minimum distance, and suppose that $d=2t+1$. We know that for every $r \in \mathbb F_q^n$ the ball 
$$ B(r,t):=\left\{x \in \mathbb F_q^n \;|\; d(x,r) \leq t \right\}$$
centered in $r$ with radius $t$ contains at most one codeword $c\in \mathcal C$. 
Obviously also the sphere
$$ S(r,t):=\left\{x \in \mathbb F_q^n \;|\; d(x,r) = t \right\}$$
has the same property.
( $d(-,-)$ is the Hamming distance).

Now fix an integer $e$ with $t<e<2t$
I have some questions.

Q1) I would like to know (or to estimate) the probability that, given an $r \in \mathbb F_q^n$, we have
$$ \left|B(r,e) \cap \mathcal C\right| \geq 2.$$
In particular I am interested in the case when $e=t+1$

Q2)  I would like to know (or to estimate) the probability that, given an $r \in \mathbb F_q^n$, we have
$$ \left|S(r,e) \cap \mathcal C\right| =1.$$
In particular I' d like to compute it when $e=t+1$

Edit:
Q3) I want to estimate the expected value of :
  $$ \left|B(r,t+1)\cap \mathcal C\right|, \;\;\; \mbox{ and }$$
  $$ \left|S(r,t+1) \cap \mathcal C\right|$$
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/943715/18398

Comment: The first thing I would try (for the case $e=t+1$) is to analyze something like Sudan's list decoding algorithm tuned up for this case. I haven't tried it, and many pitfalls may await.

Comment: Yes, of course I've studied Sudan and Guruswami's work. In fact I'm working on a different algorithm for list decoding and this problem comes up when I try to compare their algorithm with mine. The only problem is that Sudan's algorithm works only provided that $e < n-\sqrt{nk}$ (where $k+1$ is the dimension of the code). Unfortunately for high-rate codes it could happen that $t+1\geq n-\sqrt{nk}$ (e.g. when $n=63, k=50$)